Difference between comiss and comisd in x64 asm
I wrote some code to compare the value of xmm10 and xmm6 using:
comiss xmm10, xmm6 and then comisd xmm10, xmm6
The first one works, and the second one doesn't.
I tried using subss xmm10, xmm6 followed by jz .end but that didn't work
Also comisd xmm10, xmm6 crashes the program while comiss xmm10, xmm6 doesn't
Any ideas why this happens?
Note: I'm using nasm with win64

Consult instruction set reference. comiss is for 32 bit single precision, comisd is for 64 bit double precision. Use whichever is appropriate for the data you have loaded previously. subss does not set flags so you can't use it with jz.

Related: Intel x86_64 assembly compare signed double precision floats

I'm using 64 bit double precision. Also according to the docs, subss sets flags

Then you want comisd. You seem to be reading bad docs then.

The difference between the COMISS and COMISD instruction is the precision of the floats they operate on. In general, if an instruction ends with SS, it operates on single precision (32-bit) floats. If it ends with SD, it operates on double precision (64-bit) floats. The reason your program crashes if because the XMM registers do not contain enough data for double precision float operations, assuming you used single precision instructions beforehand.

comisd itself can't crash a program unless you unmask FP exceptions first (with ldmxcsr), and one of the operands contains a NaN.  (Or some other invalid operands like comparing +INF to another +INF is I think can raise the invalid flag.)  A buggy program due to branching the wrong way can of course lead to crashes, but the question doesn't have a [mcve] or any details about it.

Anyway, your answer says "the XMM registers do not contain enough data for double precision float operations", but that can't literally be true.  An XMM is always 128 bits, comisd simply looks at the low 64.  If you zero-extended a 32-bit float into an XMM with movss xmm0, [mem], the double will represent zero or a subnormal (exponent = 0 with non-zero mantissa).

Yes, the register is not “literally” true, but the rest of the register contains garbage or data not be used for the instruction.

Right, so that won't make comisd fault.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comisd - SIMD FP exceptions are masked by default (in MXCSR), so an "invalid" FP operation just sets a bit in MXCSR, not making your program crash with SIGFPE.
